# Ionic - IFrame with session coockie

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, session-cookies

We have a small web application which has mobile ui and desktop ui implemented. Now we would like to have a mobile app too. The easiest way would be to create an ionic app and iframe the site into it.

I created the app it is working well with localhost but it doesn't set the coockies for our staging environment.

**Any idea how we can solve it?**

The code is pretty simple so far:

```
<ion-app>
  <iframe src="https://ourdomain.com/"  style="width:100%;height:100%" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: In which language your embedded app is developed ? I can't directly answer to your question because I have the same kind of problem but if you just want to have a mobile app easily and you work on a secure contest (https / certificate environnement), just take a look at what a progressive web app is. (PWA)

Comment: @Karakayn at the end I moved to that too.